Can't get voicemail audio and transcription sent in the same email
I've been having a heck of a time getting Twilio to send my voicemails and transcriptions in the same email. I've used the following guide to get started:
https://www.twilio.com/en-us/blog/forward-voicemail-recordings-to-email
This was a great starting point, but for our needs we wanted a copy of the voicemail recording attached to the email sent by SendGrid. Thankfully, I came across the article at https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/twilio/articles/77782468/send-voicemail-audio-to-email, which gave me exactly what I was looking for.
However the trouble comes when trying to add the audio transcription to that same email. Here is my flow in studio: 
I have the callback URL for voice transcription in the "recordVoicemail" widget set to the URL of the function used in "fowardVoicemail". The issue is that it looks like the fowardVoicemail function runs twice. First it runs and "event.TranscriptionText" is shown as "undefined" in my email, and then a second time with the text present.
I can correct this by removing the steps in the flow and just running the functions directly from the callback URL for transcription, but anytime the transcription text is present in the email, my audio file is empty.
Here's the code for my functions.
delayForwardVM:
const sleep = (delay) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, delay));

exports.handler = async (context, event, callback) => {
  const delay = event.delay || 5000;
  await sleep(delay);
  return callback(null, `Timer up: ${delay}ms`);
};

forwardVoicemail:
// Define Handler function required by all Twilio functions
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {

  // Initialize SendGrid mail sending
  const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
  var request = require('request').defaults({
      encoding: null
  });

  // Function to capture and save voicemail as mp3
  function doCall(callback) {
    request.get({
      url: event.url + '.mp3',
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + new Buffer.from(context.ACCOUNT_SID + ":" + context.AUTH_TOKEN).toString("base64")
      }
    },
    function(error, response, body) {
      callback(Buffer.from(body).toString('base64'));
    });
  }

  // Run message capture function
  doCall(function(response) {
    // Build SendGrid mail request and define message params
    sgMail.setApiKey(context.SENDGRID_API_SECRET);
    const msg = {
      to: context.TO_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
      from: context.FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
      subject: `Afterhours Voicemail from ${event.From}`,
      text: `See attachment to review the voicemail. Also, here is a transcription:\n\n ${event.TranscriptionText}`,
      attachments: [{
        content: response,
        filename: "Voicemail.mp3",
        type: "audio/mpeg",
        disposition: "attachment"
      }]
    };
    // Send the email
    sgMail.send(msg).then(response => {
      callback();
    });
  });
}

I'm at a loss here, hoping someone might be able to help. Thanks!

When you execute this function as a transcription callback the recording url changes from event.url to event.RecordingUrl. I think once you change this you can remove delayForwardVM and  forwardVoicemail from your flow.
